# Get autocomplete to display candidates only when tab is pressed

Tags: yasnippet, auto-complete-mode

I've set up auto-complete on emacs to display completion candidates, and it seems to be working well so far.  I'm finding the constant display (and changes in display) distracting when I type, and I would like to get auto-complete to show completion candidates only when I press a key, preferably the tab key.

Can this be done?  Here's my current configuration (including yasnippet, which I want to respond to the tab keypress first):

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure t
  :config
    (yas-global-mode 1)
  :pin gnu
)

(use-package auto-complete
  :ensure t
  :config
  (progn
    (require 'auto-complete-config)
    (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
    (ac-config-default)
    (ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
    (ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>"))
  :pin melpa
)
```

This shows completion candidates continuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```el
(setq ac-auto-start nil)
```

> `ac-auto-start`
>
> Specify how completion will be started. t means always starting completion automatically. nil means never started automatically. An integer means completion will not be started until the value is more than a length of the completion target string.

It's described in the [Auto-Complete User Manual](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md#not-to-complete-automatically).

Comment: Thanks -- it works.  And thanks for the pointer to the manual.